# Testing Spring Restful web services with jUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am new to Spring and am overwhelmed with alot of the new terminology. What I am trying to accomplish is in a junit test, I want to test the result of a a get method in json form and compare it an expected result. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: DO you want to test a REST controller method? Then I'd say you should use an integration test, not an unit test.

Comment: Yes, a rest controller. I specified j unit as it is the only testing tool I know. Is there a tool for integration testing for Spring? Also, would it not be a good idea to do both integration and unit testing?

Comment: You do not do unit test for REST controller but its integration testing .Try Mockito JUnit Runner for testing . You will find lot of example online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Unit test the controller. This isn't as useful as it sounds, as one "should" have minimal code (usually just validation) in the rest controller methods, and logic in services.
2. Integration test your endpoints. This involves spinning up a full spring application and running tests against endpoints while having f.e. test data in the database. You can start your app from within maven in pre-integration-tests, and stop it in post-integration-tests.

Comment: That is interesting. Are there Spring specific tools for this or are there other third party tools for this?

Comment: I find it funny that anything non-Spring is "third-party" :-D. Now, you can set up everything using maven plugins, and a good starting point is https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

Comment: Haha yeah, I might have worded that wrong. How does this tool compare to SoapUI and spring's testing framework?

Comment: Well, we use it to automatically run all tests - unit and integration tests when  a feature branch is merged. It's maven, so it integrates nicely with existing workflows, and it's not a tool - it's something that you buold your workflow with.